# Using wm_iconbitmap and image file types that support multiple colors

Tags: python, image, icons, tkinter, imageicon

I have created an icon for my program, using file.xbm. I have realized that this is only a black and white image. Is there a way to have a colored one in linux (i.e. more than two colors)?

```
from Tkinter import * 

root = Tk() 
root.title("My Window")
bitmap = PhotoImage(file="tv.gif")
b=Button(root,image=bitmap).pack()

root.wm_iconbitmap('@/home/brandon/Show Tracker/tv.xbm')

root.iconbitmap('@/home/brandon/Show Tracker/tv.xbm')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how many colors?  Tkinter has a background / foreground color option for bitmaps, so you can set 2 colors

Comment: NO like a custom image that was made in Photoshop, with alot of colors. Is there away of using a bmp or gif or any other file type beside the 2 color files.

Comment: What is the image that you want? Is it the icon or the bitmap?